# All keys of object to current block level

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that gets the values of the from elements based on the ids. It looks like this:

```
getFormValues({name:0, desc:0, age:0});
```

Is there anyway to make this like a module? So that `name`, `desc`, `age` become variables.

So like I wanted to do this:

```
import * from getFormValues({name:0, desc:0, age:0});
alert(name);
```

I was hoping to avoid the duplication by doing:

```
let {name, desc, age} = from getFormValues({name:0, desc:0, age:0});
```

Or maybe destructure like this:

```
let fields = {name:0, desc:0, age:0};
let { ...Object.keys(fields) } = getFormValues({name:0, desc:0, age:0});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const getFormValues = () => ({ name: 'aaa', desc: 'bbb', age: 'ccc' });

const { name, desc, age } = getFormValues({name:0, desc:0, age:0});
console.log(name);
```

If you want to avoid repetition, you can use the [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), but using it is discouraged.

```js
const getFormValues = () => ({ name: 'aaa', desc: 'bbb', age: 'ccc' });

with (getFormValues({name:0, desc:0, age:0})) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

Note that, as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) says:

> Using `with` is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode.

Comment: Oh wow that is awesome! Accepted. :) Thanks Gothdo. Out of chance, is it possible for like a conditional destructure like `let { ...Object.keys(fields) } = getFormValues(fields)`?

Comment: @Noitidart AFAIK, no.

Comment: Might want to point out that `with` is (basically) deprecated and won't work in strict mode.

Comment: Can we stop telling people to use `with` ? Both code snippets also make no sense. `getFormValues` does not have a parameter so why are you calling it with an Object? What are you trying to demonstrate?

Comment: @FelixKling I added that to my answer.

Comment: @naomik In the OP's code they're calling the function with an object, so I wanted to make my code consistent with it.